# ANDROID_HOME not set error in Ionic framework

Tags: android, ionic-framework, ubuntu-14.04

I am trying to develop an application using ionic framework in my ubuntu 14.04 system. Eventhough I set ANDROID_HOME in bashrc

```
ionic build android
```

command says that ANDROID_HOME is not set. I am able to run android command from terminal. How should I solve this issue?

Comment: did you reload your `~/,bashrc` after adding `ANDROID_HOME`? What's the output of `echo $ANDROID_HOME`?

Answer (score 0):

just add an environment variable `ANDROID_HOME` that points to the android sdk path.

On ubuntu just add this to your `~/.bashrc` file :

```
export ANDROID_HOME=/path/to/your/sdk
```